# Start a table cell from a second column

Tags: html

Can I have a table with few rows in which the second row to start under the second column?
Something like this:

```
+-----------+----------------+
|           |                |
|           |                |
+-----------+----------------+
            |                |
            |                |
+-----------+----------------+
|           |                |
|           |                |
+-----------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. But you can make it look like so by using right border and background colors.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gkuQD/

Comment: Thank you sir. I don't know why I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could have:

```
<tr><td>Content1</td><td>Content2</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>Content3</td>
<td>Content4</td><td>Content5</td></tr>
```

This may be what you're looking for.